# php strtotime one week ago wrong?

Tags: php, strtotime

I need to get the milliseconds of exactly on week ago.

I tried this:

```
$this->weekDate = strtotime("-1 week");
echo($this->weekDate);
```

it returns:

```
1422536434
```

which according to this conversion tool:
http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm
is

```
Samstag, 17. Januar 1970 11:08 Uhr GMT
```

Anybody an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Do you want miliseconds

Comment: A Unix timestamp of `1422536434` is `2015-01-29 14:00:34 UST`..... if you need milliseconds then multiply by 1000, or use DateTime objects

Comment: The timestamp is in seconds!

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to multiply by 1000

Comment: @JakobAbfalter And now? Do you going to delete this question or will it be on the Stack under unanswered forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code is printing the time in seconds Use the code below

```
$this->weekDate = strtotime("-1 week");
echo($this->weekDate * 1000);
```

The output of the above code will be

```
1,422,536,434,000
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the timezones (you didn't mention when you were trying to calculate the 1 week ago so it's hard to tell what output you expected).

Try this:

```
//get current time
$now = time();
//output in human readable format
echo 'now: ' . date('r', $now) . '<br />';
//calculate same time 1 week ago
$this->weekDate = strtotime("-1 week", $now);
//output it to compare
echo '1 week ago: ' . date('r', weekAgo));
```

Comment: Wrong, read the comments! It's because the unix timestamp is in seconds!

Comment: You're right, the online service expects it to be in miliseconds. Still if the timezones will not match the outputted time string might be wrong.